# SQLite command line shell stuck on ...> , CTRL+D not working

Tags: sqlite, command-line

I've just started learning Databases, and the instructor is teaching SQLite with the command line shell. I downloaded sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3350400.zip from sqlite.org/download

When I enter false commands, like the first two you can see, I get the correct error messages. But when I enter a syntax error: ("Steve, 87654) for example, it's stuck on ...> waiting for more input. 
After searching on the internet, users suggested the solution "CTRL+D", but it doesn't work for me. CTRL+C however just exits sqlite3.

My question: How do I get out of ...> to continue with my commands? Why CTRL+D doesn't work for me, to get out of the ...> because of the syntax error or other possible causes? How do I fix my problem?

```
C:\Users\myUser>sqlite3 test.db
SQLite version 3.35.4 2021-04-02 15:20:15
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> SELECT * FROM contacts;
Tim|654321|tim@email.com
Brian|1234|brian@mygmail.com
sqlite> INSERT INTO contacts VALUES("Steve", 87654);
Error: table contacts has 3 columns but 2 values were supplied
sqlite> INSERT INTO contacts VALUES(Steve, 87654);
Error: no such column: Steve
sqlite> INSERT INTO contacts VALUES("Steve, 87654);  // Intentional syntax error //
   ...> ^D  // Entered CTRL+D //
   ...> ;
   ...>     // Entered CTRL+C //
Error: unrecognized token: ""Steve, 87654)"

C:\Users\myUser>
```

Comment: `INSERT INTO contacts VALUES("Steve, 87654);` is incorrect, there's `"` missing after `"Steve` which causes sqlite to wait for end of string value input.

Comment: @vasek I am aware that the last command is incorrect, assuming you know I know that. You're suggesting to end the string, so I can get out of the ...> by intentionally getting an error (since I wouldn't want an invalid input to register), for example continuing with "); and getting the error: "Error: table contacts has 3 columns but 1 values were supplied" .But that still doesn't answer my other questions.
1. What if I get stuck again in another ...> that wasn't a syntax error, how do I get out of it?
2. Why CTRL+D doesn't work? It supposedly breaks out of the ...>

Answer (score 1):

You need to

- a) close the quotes using **"** and
- b) finish the command line using **;**

  - can do both together (as in the first example)

e.g. :-

```
sqlite> INSERT INTO contacts VALUES("Steve,87654);
   ...> anything
   ...> ^D
   ...> ;
   ...> '
   ...> ";
Error: near ";": syntax error
sqlite> INSERT INTO contacts VALUES("Steve,87654);
   ...> "
   ...> ;
Error: near ";": syntax error
```

Of course you could even do something like :-

```
sqlite> INSERT INTO contacts VALUES("Steve,87654);
sqlite> INSERT INTO contacts VALUES("Steve,87654);
   ...> ",0987,'steve@email.com');
sqlite> SELECT * FROM contacts;
Tim|654321|tim@email.com
Brain|1234|brian@mygmail.com
Steve,87654);
|987|steve@email.com
```